# How to redirect all pages that contain an specific word using the .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a bunch of indexed pages that start with the same word and they are all 404 so I want to redirect them all to the homepage of the site. The server is Apache, so I would like to use the .htaccess file. But the problem is that "the word" is not always just after de main domain.
This was a hacked prestashop with injection of pages, already cleaned, and I'm trying to clean up google's index.

And another doubt is, would it be good for google to correct like this. I've the feeling that this will be a problem because I'll be telling google that those pages exist.

For example:

https://example.com/blablapage-1blabla/

https://example.com/page-2blablabla/

https://example.com/blablba-page-3/

thanks to everyone